# kafka logs grows too high

Tags: linux, logging, apache-kafka

I can see `kafka logs` are growing rapidly and flooding the filesystem.

How can i change settings for kafka to write less logs and rotate this logs frequently.

location of files is - `/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.2.2/logs` and their size -

```
5.9G    server.log.2020-11-24-14
5.9G    server.log.2020-11-24-15
5.9G    server.log.2020-11-24-16
5.7G    server.log.2020-11-24-17
```

sample logs from above file.

```
[2020-11-24 14:59:59,999] WARN Exception when following the leader (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.common.AtomicFileOutputStream.write(AtomicFileOutputStream.java:74)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.writeLongToFile(QuorumPeer.java:1391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.setCurrentEpoch(QuorumPeer.java:1426)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.syncWithLeader(Learner.java:454)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:83)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:981)
[2020-11-24 14:59:59,999] INFO shutdown called (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
java.lang.Exception: shutdown Follower
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.shutdown(Follower.java:169)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:985)
[2020-11-24 14:59:59,999] INFO Shutting down (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FollowerZooKeeperServer)
[2020-11-24 14:59:59,999] INFO LOOKING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2020-11-24 14:59:59,999] INFO New election. My id =  1, proposed zxid=0x1000001d2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2020-11-24 14:59:59,999] INFO Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x1000001d2 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
```

it also writes to `/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.2.2/kafka.log`.

```
[2020-12-05 16:51:10,109] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-30 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-12-05 16:51:10,109] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-36 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-12-05 16:51:10,109] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-42 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-12-05 16:51:10,110] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-48 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-12-05 17:01:09,528] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-12-05 17:11:09,528] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

kafka is used for elastic stack.

below is the entry from `server.properties` file.

```
# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/var/log/kafka
```

it has log files as

```
/var/log/kafka
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 heartbeat-1
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-12
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 auditbeat-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 apm-2
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-28
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 filebeat-2
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-38
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-44
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-6
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-16
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 metricbeat-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-22
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka users 4.0K Dec  5 16:51 __consumer_offsets-32
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka users  747 Dec  5 18:02 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka users    4 Dec  5 18:02 log-start-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka users  749 Dec  5 18:03 replication-offset-checkpoint
```

no `DEBUG` level logs is enabled in files in `/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.2.2/config` path.

How can I make sure it doesn't make such a hugh files in `/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.2.2/logs` and also how can I rotate them regularly with compression.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`log.dirs` is the actual broker storage, not the process logs, therefore should not be in `/var/log` with other process logs

Almost 6G a day is not unreasonable, but you can modify the log4j.properties file to only keep around 1 or 2 days from the rolling file appender; I do not believe they can be compressed, but that is more a control of log4j, not Kafka itself, so refer log4j documentation...

Generally, as any Linux administration task, you'd have separate disk volumes for `/var/log`, your OS storage, and any dedicated disks for server data - say a mount at `/kafka`

Comment: That's very good to distinguish broker storage from process logs. Putting them together may be very confusing especially if someone just starts to learn kafka.